# How to pass Proxy settings to custom updater code with Install4j API?

Tags: install4j

We are implementing the updater service using the install4j APIs (without using the Updater.exe). We could successfully use the APIs as below to get the possible update version

```
UpdateCheckRequest updateCheckRequest = new UpdateCheckRequest(updatesUrl).applicationDisplayMode(ApplicationDisplayMode.UNATTENDED)
                                                                .askForProxy(false).connectTimeout(10000).readTimeout(20000);
UpdateDescriptor updateDescriptor = UpdateChecker.getUpdateDescriptor(updateCheckRequest);

return updateDescriptor.getPossibleUpdateEntry();
```

However, we are missing the below JVM arguments, (to set proxy settings and enable logging) which are available in the updater screens.

```
-Dinstall4j.noProxyAutoDetect=true
-DproxySet=true
-DproxyHost= “”,
-DproxyPort=””
-DproxyAuth="true"
-DproxyAuthUser=””
-DproxyAuthPassword=””

-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=${installer:sys.installationDir}/logs/patch-agent-updater.log
```

Please let us know how to pass them to the custom updater ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the update checker runs in the same process, so you can set these properties via `System.setProperty`.